# Count commerce orders by day and total in views

Tags: views, commerce

I have being trying to modify the default commerce orders view "admin/commerce/orders
" to do the following.

I want the output to list orders by date, number of products, tax and Total

Is this possible with views or do i need to look into a custom module? I cant get anything that is remotly close.
The best i can get is to count orders.

[image: Example of what im trying to achieve]

Comment: Try making a view from scratch, not modify existing one. If you need huge changes, like, revolution, it might be simply easier and faster to start from a blank page.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for the advice I have tried that but I cant achieve this outcome.